# How to set sudo privilege with public jupyter notebook image

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jupyter-notebook, yaml, docker-image

I'm currently using gcr.io/kubeflow-images-public/tensorflow-1.15.2-notebook-gpu:1.0.0 deployed in a kubernete cluster. But it's by default no root permission in the notebook server. I have tried to use other images such as jupyter/datascience-notebook where you can allow sudo by setting the parameters. The docker command is

`docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 --user root -e NB_GID=100 -e GEN_CERT=yes -e GRANT_SUDO=yes jupyter/datascience-notebook`

But I have to use yaml file to deploy the server in a cluster. The question is how to convert this docker command to a StatefulSet yaml file? Or are there other suggestions which allows sudo in a jupyter notebook server in Kubernetes?

Comment: Why do you need root permission in the container?  Is there setup you could do in a Dockerfile instead?

Comment: @DavidMaze Because I want to install firefox and it requires sudo. I'm developing an app with DL models which require GPU, so I have to run the app in the remote environment. But I have to see how the webpages look like while I write the code. That's why I need to install a browser in the environment with GPU.

Comment: You should install that in your image's `Dockerfile` generally.  Anything you install in a container will get lost as soon as the container exits.  For an interactive GUI tool like a Web browser, you may find the setup easier to use a local browser connecting to a process inside the container.